# How to present error when #define is incomplete in Flex?

Tags: parsing, lex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to present to the screen an error output when the user enters an incomplete 
define , e.g :

```
#define A  // this is wrong , error message should appear

#define A 5 // this is the correct form , no error message would be presented
```

but it doesn't work , here's the code :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%s FULLCOMMENT
%s LINECOMMENT
%s DEFINE
%s INCLUDE
%s PRINT
%s PSEUDO_C_CODE

STRING [^ \n]*

%%


<FULLCOMMENT>"*/"   {  BEGIN INITIAL; }
<FULLCOMMENT>.      { /* Do Nothing       */ }

<INCLUDE>"<stdio.h>"|"<stdlib.h>"|"<string.h>"  { BEGIN INITIAL;  }
<INCLUDE>.      { printf("error\n");    return 0 ;  }

<DEFINE>[ \t]       {  printf("eat a space within define\n"); } 
<DEFINE>{STRING}    {  printf("eat string %s\n" , yytext);}
<DEFINE>\n      {  printf("eat a break line within define\n"); BEGIN INITIAL; }



"#include"      {   BEGIN INCLUDE;  }
"#define"       {   printf("you gonna to define\n");   BEGIN DEFINE;    }
"#define"+.             {   printf("error\n");  }                                                                                                                                   

%%

int yywrap(void)  { return 1;  }  // Callback at end of file
int main(void)  { 
    yylex(); 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Here is the output :

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./a.out
#define A 4
error
A 4
#define A
error
A
```

Comment: I retagged this; as I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do w/ Adobe/Apache Flex (the UI Framework).  gnu-flex or lex are generally used for the lexical parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule "#define"+. is longer and gets precedence over the earlier #define even for correct input. You could say just this :-

"#define"[:space:]*$ {printf("error\n"); }

Consider using the -dvT options with flex to get detailed debug output. Also I am not sure if you need such extensive use of states for anything except maybe comments. But you would know better.